# Unable to Create a Google Cloud App Engine Production Production Service

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm new to GCP and I was just trying to setup a GCP App Engine Production environment and I was using this [linked](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/app-engine-setup) documentation. However, I'm coming across an issue when wherever I create a production version, it will disappear a few minutes later. I already have billing setup and everything and I'm unable to figure out why this is happening.